# SSL/HTTPS based on port instead of subdomain?

Tags: port, https

I have my home server setup with many docker services running on a VM.  I have like 10+ services.  Up till now I've had all of them running locally with no SSL authentication.  I access them through a local DNS such as:

```
green.myhomedomain.com:8080 (service1 - say grafana)
green.myhomedomain.com:8079 (service2 - say zigbee2mqtt)
green.myhomedomain.com:8078 (service3 - and so forth)
```

I added a new one but this one I tried setting up SSL on, so I added my letsencrypt wildcard SSL to that site (*.myhomedomain.com)

the SSL works great and I get connected to it with no issues

`https://green.myhomedomain.com:8077 (service4 - using SSL)`

But now when I go back to the old non-SSL sites, the web browser errors out, because it tries to load an SSL cert for my `green.myhomedomain.com`, but they aren't encrypt.  I don't want it to look for a cert for those other ports.  Only for 8077.  If I manually type in http:// vs https://  it always just converts http to https for any site if I've visited the SSL site.

If I clear cookies, it works again on those other sites, up until I go back to the ssl/8077 service. Then it starts to wants SSL for everything again.  This breaks all of my services.

I've tried this in firefox and vivaldi. Same effect in each.

Is there a way to make browsers only load SSL certs specifically for the one port but not the others?

I'm not great at networking, so I fear this just isn't doable and I'm going to have to separate all my serivces to separate subdomains, but I have a lot and it's going to be a lot of work.

Comment: Is your new service (the one that you set up TLS on) also using HSTS by any chance?